# Publish external packages

Tags: f#, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I want to publish nuget packages from FAKE. But I don't use NuGet to create those packages. I have OctoPack installed in some projects and I'm running build with /p:RunOctoPack=True. This dumps .nupkg files in bin directory.
How do I then collect those packages and push them to NuGet server? I can't seem to make NuGetPublish and FileIncludes to work together.

edit:
for now I've worked around it using ExecProcess

```
Target "Publish" (fun _ ->
    let result = ExecProcess (fun info ->  
                   info.FileName <- "MySolution/.nuget/NuGet.exe"
                   info.WorkingDirectory <- "MySolutionDirectory"
                   info.Arguments <- "push \"**/bin/**/*.nupkg\" -s http://my-nuget-server") TimeSpan.MaxValue

    if result <> 0 then failwithf "NuGet.exe push returned with a non-zero exit code"
```

)

Answer (score 3):

As Steffen mentioned, you can use NuGet Publish task, it is described in the API but there is no tutorial for this.

Your script code could look like this:

```
NuGetPublish (fun nugetParams -> 
    { nugetParams with
        AccessKey = "nuget_api_key"
        PublishUrl = "nuget_feed_url"
        Project = "project_name"
        Version = "project_version"
        WorkingDir = "nupkg_file_location"
    }
)
```

Where:

- Project - the main part of you nupkg file name (i.e. `My.Super.Project`)
- Version - the version part of your nupkg file name (i.e. `0.0.10`)
- WorkingDir - the location of your nukpg file

The full nupkg file name that this task will be looking for is:

`WorkingDir\Project.Version.nupkg`

Comment: Thank Alexey for the example!
I had to assign a value to OutputPath as well.  Without this, Fake tried to grab the nuget package from the folder .\NuGet\Project.Version.nupkg.  After I set OutputPath it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

We have a [NuGetPublish task](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/31a93745b427da20308ee8c6f90710b57596956d/src/app/FakeLib/NuGet/NugetHelper.fs#L391) which should do exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm personally pretty new to this whole thing. How do we use what you linked to? IE: If I already have a nupkg, and I just want to publish it, how do I do so?